# Error connecting to ODBC from EA, (but ODBC is working!!)

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am getting a perplexing message from EA.  EA used to work fine, but has suddenly stopped.  My colleagues are not having trouble.

```
The selected connection is invalid.  Please check that a DSN (or filename) has been defined and try again.
```

It happens when I run Database Builder | Right click connection | set as active connection.

I have uninstalled and then reinstalled a SQLServer ODBC driver.  I have tried 32 bit and 64 bit ODBC drivers, and nothing works.

Does anyone know under what circumstances EA spits out this message?  My ODBC has been verified to be working via other tests (connect via odbc in another app and it's fine!)

EA version 12.0.1215

Thank you,
Juraj

Comment: I got no clue how to start this "Database Builder". Opening the menu and it puts me on an empty form with no choice to do anything. A typical Sparx product :-(

Comment: I think you need a deluxe version of EA that has database builder enabled.  It should be available under Tools menu in EA 12.0.

Comment: I looked into the version comparison and I could not find any hint on the database builder. If it's version dependent, it should show me that and not open a not usable dialog. Awww, well. So good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

We still don't know what caused it.  But it was a network install over some App-V client that had issues with my profile / account.  I'll post more if I learn why it was happening, in case it helps anyone.

A local install to my local drive seemed to fix it.  My colleagues have the standard App-V client install, and have no issues however.

Hmmm.

Juraj